# PHP - check if a string is a multibyte alphanumeric character

Tags: php, utf-8, multibyte

I need to find out if a string contains exactly one alphanumeric character. The obvious solution would be to check the length and ASCII code (`A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9`) - but the problem is that I'm working with UTF-8 strings and accented letters like `á`, `ř`, `č` etc.

Is there a simple way to check if an UTF-8 character is alphanumeric (latin alphabet letter, possibly accented, or a number)?

Comment: By "alphanumeric" you mean a *Latin alphabet* letter? Or any *letter* from *any* alphabet?

Comment: Yes, Latin alphabet letter.

Answer (score 0):

This is easily done with a [regular expression](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
$count = preg_match_all('/\w/u', $string);
if ($count === 1) {
    echo "One alphanumeric character found";
}
```

`\w` will match any "word" character, which are letters, numbers, and underscore.  The `u` modifier treats the string as unicode so it will include accented characters.

If matching underscores is a problem you could use `[:alnum:]` as a [character class](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) match instead.